# How to create a Procedure that inserts records from one table to another and also checking validity? PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am having trouble figuring out how to successfully create this procedure and not even sure if I'm on the right start.

```
create or replace procedure enroll_student2(p_stu_ID number,p_class_id number)
as
declare
    stu_standing number;
    course_standing number;
begin
    if stu_standing >= course_standing THEN
        insert into enroll (stu_ID,class_id)
        select stu_id,class_id
        from student,class_sched
        where stu_id=p_stu_ID and class_id=p_class_id;
    else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Requirement not met');
    end if;
END;
/
```

I am trying to enroll the student into the course while also checking if their student standing is equal to or higher than the course standing.
[Reference of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP3FF.png)

Comment: You need to populate your declared variables and stop using implicit (comma) joins.

Answer (score 2):

Your IF condition relies on two variables which you do not populate. Presumably these values come from the STUDENT and CLASS tables. So I think you need to select the pertinent records first, then evaluate the IF condition.

Something like this:

```
create or replace procedure enroll_student2
  (p_stu_ID number,p_class_id number)
as

    l_stu_standing number;
    l_course_standing number;

begin

    select s.stu_standing
    into l_stu_standing
    from student s
    where s.stu_id = p_stu_id;


    select c.course_standing
    into l_course_standing
    from class_sched cs
         inner join course c on c.course_id = cs.course_id
    where c.class_id = p_class_id;

    if l_stu_standing >= l_course_standing then
        insert into enroll (stu_ID, class_id)
        values (p_stu_id, p_class_id); 
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Requirement not met');
    end if;

end;
/
```

Note: you haven't posted your data model so I took some guesses: consequently you may need to fix compilation errors. Also I haven't put in any error handling for obvious potential exceptions (NO_DATA_FOUND, TOO_MANY_ROWS, etc) which you probably should include.

You don't need DECLARE, in fact you'll get a compilation error. It's required for anonymous blocks but for named procedures and functions the AS (or IS) keyword denotes the start of the declaration section. (This is a common mistake for people starting out in PL/SQL and to be fair it appears to be  inconsistent with declaration of triggers.)

Finally, remember that using DBMS_OUTPUT to report program failure is not a robust tactic. It's no good if the user is running with SERVEROUTPUT off, or when **another program** calls this one.

Answer (score 0):

From the referenced ERD the following should work. However, I've not tested it.

```
create or replace procedure enroll_student2(p_stu_id number,p_class_id number)
as
begin
    insert into enroll (s.stu_id,cs.class_id)
          select s.stu_id,cs.class_id
            from student      s 
               , class_sched  cs
           where s.stu_id = p_stu_id 
             and cs.class_id = p_class_id
             and s.stu_standing >= cs.course_standing;
             
    if sql%rowcount = 0 
    then 
        dbms_output.put_line('Requirement not met');
    end if;
end enroll_student2;
```